# Gatling feeder will crash when using the same feeder for multiple scenarios

Tags: gatling

I'm using the following feeder that generates two random UUIDs

```java
Iterator<Map<String, Object>> postRequestDataFeeder =
  Stream.generate((Supplier<Map<String, Object>>) () -> {
      String id = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      String version =  java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      return Map.of("id", id, "version", version);
    }
  ).iterator();
```

And I will be reusing the feeder in 5-6 scenarios, following is a sample scenario

```java
public static ScenarioBuilder dataCreationForPostRequest =
    scenario("Data creation for post request")
        .feed(postRequestDataFeeder)
        .exec(//)
        .exec(session -> {
            // save generated data to a list
            return session;
        })
```

The Gatling documentation says

> Every time a virtual user reaches this step, it will pop a record out of the Feeder, which will be injected into the user’s session,
> resulting in a new Session instance.

But when I run the simulation it will crash saying that the Feeder is empty

[image]

How can the feeder be empty if it will pop a record every time a virtual user reaches this step?
Is is not possible to reuse feeders throughout multiple scenarios?

Comment: That looks like a bug. I'm investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's indeed a [bug](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/4240) in Gatling's Java DSL. It will be fixed in Gatling 3.8.0.